# Why am I receiving NULL in R?

Tags: r

I am working in R with the package `poliscidata`, in the dataset `world`. One of the variables I need to work with, the interval variable `free_labor`, keeps getting a result of `NULL` no matter what I try to do with it - for example:

```
print(world$free_labor)
NULL

print(world$free_labor, na.rm = TRUE)
NULL

levels(world$free_labor)
NULL
```

Does anyone know why this might be happening and how I could fix it?

Comment: What does `names(world)` return? Are you sure you are using the original data.frame and haven't created a new variable with that name?

Comment: `print(world$free_labor)` produces the expected output for me.

Comment: This looks like what would happen if that column was (accidentally?) dropped from the data frame. Reloading the package data might be the easiest way to reset it. `data(poliscidata,  package = "world")` should do that.

Comment: Hello MrFlick, I think I'm using the original data.frame since I've restarted and it does the same thing. If it helps, names(world) returns this: > names(world)
 [1] "cluster"    "strata"     "has.strata"
 [4] "prob"       "allprob"    "call"      
 [7] "variables"  "fpc"        "pps"       
[10] "democ.yes"

Comment: Hello Gregor Thomas, I tried what you suggested  - other than writing it as data(world, package = "poliscidata")  - and I think it worked, thank you so much!!

Comment: So the answer appears to be that you had an object that was from a different package.